# how to control store arrays in pickle python

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

I store some from the images in the database as 128 vector arrays. My problem is that when I put new images in the dataset or delete images from dataset, pickle re-save the images that you previously saved and does not know that the array vectors has already been saved to it.

This causes When I have a lot of pictures in the dataset, it's time to spend on saving them in the pickle. How can I fix it?

```
 ├── dataset
    │   ├── jack [10 entries]
    │   ├── john [7 entries]
    │   ├── mori [24 entries]


    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--dataset", required=True,help="path to input directory of faces + images")
    ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", required=True,help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
    features = []
    faces = []
    for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
         name = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
         encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)
         for encoding in encodings:
              knownEncodings.append(encoding)
              knownNames.append(name)





    data = {"encodings": knownEncodings, "names": knownNames}
    f = open(args["encodings"], "wb")
    f.write(pickle.dumps(data))
    f.close()
```